Temporarily delete keywords from lstlistings: Some keywords are not deleted
As a follow up of a previous question Temporarily delete keywords from lstlistings, I am not able to use the same recipe for removing the keywords "TIME" or "DATE". Any idea what would be the problem here ?
\documentclass{article}

% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{mySQL}{%
  language=SQL,
  alsoletter={&},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  % alsodigit={-},
  % alsoletter={-},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test for color highlighting using the lstlistings package.
I would like to remove two keywords just in the example below.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL,deletekeywords={TIME,VALUE}]
CREATE TABLE Flights(ICAO24, CallSign, FlightPeriod, Flight, Velocity, Heading,
  VertRate, Alert, GeoAltitude) AS
SELECT ICAO24, (Rec).Value AS CallSign, (Rec).Time AS FlightPeriod,
  atTime(Flight, (Rec).Time), atTime(Velocity, (Rec).Time),
  atTime(Heading, (Rec).Time), atTime(VertRate, (Rec).Time),
  atTime(Alert, (Rec).Time), atTime(GeoAltitude, (Rec).Time)
FROM FlightsDay f, unnest(f.CallSign) AS Rec;
\end{lstlisting}

Another example of deleting keywords
\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL,deletekeywords={DATE,YEAR}]
SELECT c.CompanyName, d.Year, a.CategoryName, SUM(SalesAmount) AS SalesAmount
FROM Sales s, Customer c, Date d, Product p, Category a
WHERE s.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey AND s.OrderDateKey = d.DateKey AND
  s.ProductKey = p.ProductKey AND p.CategoryKey = a.CategoryKey
GROUP BY c.CompanyName, d.Year, a.CategoryName
ORDER BY c.CompanyName, d.Year, a.CategoryName;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

This deleted the keyword "VALUE" but not "TIME"

Similarly, this deleted the keyword "YEAR" but not "DATE"

It has been pointed out to me that, e.g., this question may be a solution for this. However, from a user perspective, I don't see whether specifying exactly the same thing for two keywords, one of them works and not the other. I would rather prefer not to go to the LaTeX code to know how to achieve this.

Same as last time? Case matters.

TIME is defined via morendkeywords:
%%
%% SQL definition (c) 1998 Christian Haul
%%                (c) 2002 Neil Conway
%%                (c) 2002 Robert Frank
%%                (c) 2003 Dirk Jesko
%%
\lst@definelanguage{SQL}%
  {morekeywords={ABSOLUTE,ACTION,ADD,ALLOCATE,ALTER,ARE,AS,ASSERTION,%
      AT,BEGIN,BETWEEN,BIT_LENGTH,BOTH,BY,CASCADE,CASCADED,CASE,CAST,%
      CATALOG,CHAR_LENGTH,CHARACTER_LENGTH,CLUSTER,COALESCE,%
      COLLATE,COLLATION,COLUMN,CONNECT,CONNECTION,CONSTRAINT,%
      CONSTRAINTS,CONVERT,CORRESPONDING,CREATE,CROSS,CURRENT_DATE,%
      CURRENT_TIME,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_USER,DAY,DEALLOCATE,%
      DEC,DEFERRABLE,DEFERED,DESCRIBE,DESCRIPTOR,DIAGNOSTICS,%
      DISCONNECT,DOMAIN,DROP,ELSE,END,EXEC,EXCEPT,EXCEPTION,EXECUTE,%
      EXTERNAL,EXTRACT,FALSE,FIRST,FOREIGN,FROM,FULL,GET,GLOBAL,%
      GRAPHIC,HAVING,HOUR,IDENTITY,IMMEDIATE,INDEX,INITIALLY,INNER,%
      INPUT,INSENSITIVE,INSERT,INTO,INTERSECT,INTERVAL,%
      ISOLATION,JOIN,KEY,LAST,LEADING,LEFT,LEVEL,LIMIT,LOCAL,LOWER,%
      MATCH,MINUTE,MONTH,NAMES,NATIONAL,NATURAL,NCHAR,NEXT,NO,NOT,NULL,%
      NULLIF,OCTET_LENGTH,ON,ONLY,ORDER,ORDERED,OUTER,OUTPUT,OVERLAPS,%
      PAD,PARTIAL,POSITION,PREPARE,PRESERVE,PRIMARY,PRIOR,READ,%
      RELATIVE,RESTRICT,REVOKE,RIGHT,ROWS,SCROLL,SECOND,SELECT,SESSION,%
      SESSION_USER,SIZE,SPACE,SQLSTATE,SUBSTRING,SYSTEM_USER,%
      TABLE,TEMPORARY,THEN,TIMEZONE_HOUR,%
      TIMEZONE_MINUTE,TRAILING,TRANSACTION,TRANSLATE,TRANSLATION,TRIM,%
      TRUE,UNIQUE,UNKNOWN,UPPER,USAGE,USING,VALUE,VALUES,%
      VARGRAPHIC,VARYING,WHEN,WHERE,WRITE,YEAR,ZONE,%
      AND,ASC,avg,CHECK,COMMIT,count,DECODE,DESC,DISTINCT,GROUP,IN,% FF
      LIKE,NUMBER,ROLLBACK,SUBSTR,sum,VARCHAR2,% FF
      MIN,MAX,UNION,UPDATE,% RF
      ALL,ANY,CUBE,CUBE,DEFAULT,DELETE,EXISTS,GRANT,OR,RECURSIVE,% DJ
      ROLE,ROLLUP,SET,SOME,TRIGGER,VIEW},% DJ
   morendkeywords={BIT,BLOB,CHAR,CHARACTER,CLOB,DATE,DECIMAL,FLOAT,% DJ
      INT,INTEGER,NUMERIC,SMALLINT,TIME,TIMESTAMP,VARCHAR},% moved here
   sensitive=false,% DJ
   morecomment=[l]--,%
   morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},%
   morestring=[d]',%
   morestring=[d]"%
  }[keywords,comments,strings]

You can use deletekeywords=[2]{TIME} to delete it:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL,{deletekeywords=[2]{TIME}}]
CREATE TABLE Flights(ICAO24, CallSign, FlightPeriod, Flight, Velocity, Heading,
  VertRate, Alert, GeoAltitude) AS
SELECT ICAO24, (Rec).Value AS CallSign, (Rec).Time AS FlightPeriod,
  atTime(Flight, (Rec).Time), atTime(Velocity, (Rec).Time),
  atTime(Heading, (Rec).Time), atTime(VertRate, (Rec).Time),
  atTime(Alert, (Rec).Time), atTime(GeoAltitude, (Rec).Time)
FROM FlightsDay f, unnest(f.CallSign) AS Rec;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


